# why inspect.getmember gives different outputs

Tags: python

first code

```
import inspect
members = inspect.getmembers(module)
print(members)
```

second code

```
import inspect
for a,b in inspect.getmembers(module):
    print(a)
```

why 'inspect.getmembers(module)' returns entirely different outputs for above cases.
consider

```
   test = [(1,2),(3,4)]
   for a,b in test:
       print(a)
```

which will print 1,3 but this logic is not applicable to inspect.getmembers()
why is that someone please explain

Comment: What is `pickle.getmembers()`? Do you mean `inspect.getmembers()`?

Comment: my mistake i meant inspect.getmembers()

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the confusion... you say _"but this logic is not applicable to inspect.getmembers()"_, but it looks like it does exactly the same thing to me. Can you show a sample of the output you're getting and describe what you expect instead?

Comment: Please don't add multiple version-specific tags (unless you're doing something like porting between versions). If your question is specific to a version, add that version tag. If it isn't, just stick with the generic python tag.

Comment: again my mistake while considering key only both are same.for my first code i considered key and its corresponding value which is a lot of discription.next time i will be more carefull about the tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run this code:

```
import inspect
import re
members = inspect.getmembers(re)
members1 = [x[0] for x in members]

members2 = []
for a,b in inspect.getmembers(re):
    members2.append(a)
print (members1 == members2)
```

to me it returns `True`. Which means that results at key level are the same, since in for you care only about keys - then you get what you want...